# Database modeling tool to generate E-R diagrams from schema or any other tool to visually represent the MySQL DB schema

Tags: mysql, schema, entity-relationship, database

I have inherited a mysql schema with around two dozen tables. I would like to create an E-R diagram (or some form of visual representation) from my the create table statements. I am looking for free open source tools which will help me do this. This will help me understand the schema better and aid others as well.

Do people have experiences with any open source tools which will help me do this? Any suggestions/recommendations will be great.

Answer (score 1):

While it won't automatically do it for you, [Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia) would be a good place to start. It is open source and even has special tools to help with E-R diagrams. I actually just finished creating an ERD for a class with this program.